# Text alignment not center in all devices

Tags: html, css, footer

I have a footer div with this code

```css
.footer {
width: 100%;
height: 50px;
position: absolute;
bottom: 0;
background-color: #DDD;
}
.center-xy {
position: absolute;
top: 50%;
left: 50%;
transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
}
.footer-text {
font-family: 'Calibri';
font-size: 0.8em;

}
.footer-text a {
text-decoration: none;
}
```

```html
<nav class="footer">
    <div class="center-xy footer-text">
        Made with <span style="color: red; font-size: 1.5em;">&hearts;</span> by <strong><a href="https://www.facebook.com/shantanuandbanerjee" target="_blank">Shantanu Banerjee</a></strong>
    </div>
</nav>
```

The problem is the `footer-text` is well centered in Laptop Screens and mobile phones. But on Mobile Phones the text comes in 2-lines.

[image]

What is the solution?

Comment: are you using Bootstrap?

Comment: Nope. No Bootstrap is being used.

Comment: Try this: https://jsfiddle.net/tk9qt41c/1/

Comment: looks like there's a lot of padding because even with adequate visible space, the text is wrapping. so reduce padding or set `white-space:nowrap`

Comment: Don't you have padding set somewhere for the footer?

Comment: @john-c-j It is looking on the fiddle, but failed on the mobile phones.

Comment: @john flex is not supported in IE for that you have to use flexbox thats why it is failing on some mobile devices

Comment: Great to hear that. :)

Comment: @PraveenPuglia post it as answer. I forgot to accept the answer :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I am not sure about the code(at the time of posting the comment),  but it looks like there's a lot of padding because even with adequate visible space, the text is wrapping. So..

- Reduce padding around the text. OR
- Apply `white-space: nowrap;` for your text.

Answer (score 0):

Just add the following css

```
.footer-text {
    min-width: 200px;
    text-align: center;
}
```

And it will be fixed.

Here's a working demo:

```css
.footer {
            width: 100%;
            height: 50px;
            position: absolute;
            bottom: 0;
            background-color: #DDD;
        }
        .center-xy {
            position: absolute;
            top: 50%;
            left: 50%;
            transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
        }
        .footer-text {
            font-family: 'Calibri';
            font-size: 0.8em;

        }
        .footer-text a {
            text-decoration: none;
        }
       .footer-text {
         min-width: 200px;
         text-align: center;
        }
```

```html
<nav class="footer">
        <div class="center-xy footer-text">
            Made with <span style="color: red; font-size: 1.5em;">&hearts;</span> by <strong><a href="https://www.facebook.com/shantanuandbanerjee" target="_blank">Shantanu Banerjee</a></strong>
        </div>
</nav>
```

Comment: It did. You just didn't try it.

Comment: I cannot set `min-width: 200px` I have other boundations too

Answer (score 0):

try this:

```css
.footer {
    position: absolute;
    bottom: 0;
    margin:0;
    background-color: #DDD;
    left:0;
    right:0;
    padding:15px 0;
    text-align:center
}
.center-xy {
   
}
.footer-text {
    font-family: 'Calibri';
    font-size: 0.8em;

}
.footer-text a {
    text-decoration: none;
}
```

```html
<nav class="footer">
        <div class="center-xy footer-text">
            Made with <span style="color: red; font-size: 1.5em;">&hearts;</span> by <strong><a href="https://www.facebook.com/shantanuandbanerjee" target="_blank">Shantanu Banerjee</a></strong>
        </div>
</nav>
```

Answer (score -1):

just use

```
.center-xy {
            position: absolute;
            top: 50%;
            left: 50%;
            transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
            -webkit-transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
            -moz-transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
            -ms-transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
            -o-transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
  }
```

Comment: No. Did not solve the problem. Only `transform` is enough on the modern browsers

Comment: You are talking about all the device so sometimes devices default browser is not modern I checked on some android devies